# Filter list of jobs (started with job_start()) by status

Tags: vimscript

I have built a list containing the "job" object as returned by job_start. The code populating the list is:

```
let g:sc_instances = get(g:, 'sc_instances', [])
let l:job = job_start('my command and args')
call add(g:sc_instances, l:job)
```

I try to filter out the instances which are no longer running.

I use the following code in the function to clean up the list:

```
let g:sc_instances = get(g:, 'sc_instances', [])
call filter(g:sc_instances, {idx, val -> job_status(val) != "run"})
```

but it always leaves the list empty after execution (removes all the items). What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok shame on me, I have badly read the documentation about filter:

> The function must return |TRUE| if the item should be kept.

So I just have to invert my condition.

```
call filter(g:sc_instances, {idx, val -> job_status(val) == "run"})
```